# How to disable text to emoji conversion?

Tags: keyboard, sms, emoji, emoticons, gboard

I have been trying to activate a service through sms, but there is a part where **'<' and '3' comes together and it turns into the heart emoji ruining the whole sms** . Is there a solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, set encoding to GSM-7. Emojis are sometimes shown when encoding is UCS-2 (UTF-16)